# Creating meaningful add URLs in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, url-routing, crud, url

For my site I have a number of `Orders` each of which contains a number of `Quotes`. A quote is always tied to an individual order, so in the quotes controller I add a quote with reference to it's order:

```
function add($orderId) {
    // function here
}
```

And the calling URL looks a bit like

```
http://www.example.com/quotes/add/1
```

It occurred to me the URLs would make more sense if they looked a bit more like

```
http://www.example.com/orders/1/quotes/add
```

As the quote is being added to order 1.

Is this something it's possible to achieve in CakePHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation for [defining routes](http://book.cakephp.org/view/948/Defining-Routes).

Something like this should do the trick:

```
Router::connect(
    '/orders/:id/quotes/add',
    array('controller' => 'quotes', 'action' => 'add'),
    array('id' => '[0-9]+')
);
```

You will be able to access the ID with `$this->params['id']` in `QuotesController::add()`.

**Edit:**

Also, have a look at the documentation for [passing parameters to action](http://book.cakephp.org/view/949/Passing-parameters-to-action).

It is possible to pass the ID in as a parameter of the controller action like so:

```
Router::connect(
    '/orders/:id/quotes/add',
    array('controller' => 'quotes', 'action' => 'add'),
    array('pass' => array('id'), 'id' => '[0-9]+')
);
```

You can then access the ID with `$id` in `QuotesController::add($id)`.